# Unable to center text using text-overflow: ellipsis

Tags: html, css

I have created a div with text that uses an ellipsis when it overflows the text. When the text doesn't overflow, the text is centered.
[image]

However, when the text overflows outside of the div, the text is not centered with the ellipsis. It almost looks like it's aligned to the left.
[image]

How can I center the text with the ellipsis?

```css
#alert-message {
  position: absolute;
  width: 960px;
  height: 196px;
  top: 1000px;
  left: 120px;
  padding-top: 44px;
  line-height: 142%;
  font-family: 'sequel100black-65uploadedfile' !important;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div id="alert-message">thisisextremelylongtext<br>123 viewers</div>
```

Comment: Looks centered to me. - See https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/GRzjQBR

Comment: Thank you for your response @Paulie_D. In your codepen there still looks like there is some whitespace after the ellipsis compared to the 'T' at the start of the text where there is no white space at all?

Comment: That's a function of the ellipsis glyph I suspect.

Comment: I thought as much, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

you just need to add padding left/right and set **box-sizing** to **border-box** to avoid increase in width due to left/right padding refer [box-sizing mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Thanks

```css
#alert-message {
border:1px solid red;

display: inline-block;
//  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 196px;
  //top: 1000px;
  //left: 120px;
  padding: 44px 20px 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 142%;
  //font-family: 'sequel100black-65uploadedfile' !important;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div id="alert-message">thisisextremelylongtext<br>123 viewers</div>
```

Comment: @pyefacepoker have you tried the above-said approach, not why someone downvote to my solution